# Is it a good idea to be able to award only a partial bounty?

Tags: feature-request, bounties

If a bounty is offered for a question but noone answers the question to the necessary degree, shouldnt we be able to award the best answer only a partial bounty? This is not to say that we can assign the rest to someone else or get it back. Just that I want to appropriately reward someone for their effort.

Comment: Maybe if your question had been: can we divide a bounty among multiple answers. (Of course, then this would have been a duplicate.)

Comment: @MrLister Noone has addressed why this isnt a good idea. Its not the idea that you suggest, but I think its still a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

First, you won't ever be able to get a bounty back. That's kind of an important part of keeping bounties meaningful.

Second, part of your request is *kind of* already in place. If you don't explicitly award the bounty after 8 days, then the system will award half of the bounty to the highest voted answer posted during the bounty period (as long as it has a net score of at least +2).

Comment: The point, as stated wasnt to get anything back. It is to be able to choose who gets how much depending on the amount of effort put in. Right now, we cant even choose who gets it.